# Variable dependency of submodule with property from settings.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I have a sample maven project with the following structure:

```
parent
   frontend
   backend
```

Frontend depends on Backend.
Backend has a database driver dependency for testing. However, this dependency should be dependent on the developers settings.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${database.driver.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${database.driver.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${database.driver.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In my settings.xml I have this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>database</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <database.driver.groupId>mysql</database.driver.groupId>
            <database.driver.artifactId>mysql-connector-java</database.driver.artifactId>
            <database.driver.version>5.1.9</database.driver.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

When I run only the backend the properties are correctly substituted.
However, if I run frontend (or parent) transitive dependencies are not available for frontend because it can't substitute the properties anymore:

```
 [WARNING] The POM for de.phil.mvntest:business:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for de.phil.mvntest:business:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for ${database.driver.groupId}:${database.driver.artifactId}:jar with value '${database.driver.artifactId}' does not match a valid id pattern. @ 
 [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${database.driver.groupId}:${database.driver.artifactId}:jar with value '${database.driver.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. @
```

The funny part is, that if I move the profile declaration into the parent's pom.xml it works fine!

So my question is, why are the properties of a submodule not substituted when they come from the settings.xml.

Note:
"help:active-profiles -N" shows that the profile from the settings.xml is active.

Note2: The Maven version came with STS and is Embedded 3.0.4

---

### Following the settins.xml and poms

backend

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.phil.mvntest</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${database.driver.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${database.driver.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${database.driver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

fontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.phil.mvntest</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.phil.mvntest</groupId>
            <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.phil.mvntest</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>frontend</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>database</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <database.driver.groupId>mysql</database.driver.groupId>
                <database.driver.artifactId>mysql-connector-java</database.driver.artifactId>
                <database.driver.version>5.1.9</database.driver.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating dependencies in profiles isn't very safe. The only case in which it works fairly well is to run tests against different dependencies, and even that is safer with the maven-invoker-plugin instead. The pom that gets deployed can only have one dependency set.